# Modeling hierarchical data in django with polymorphic node types

Tags: django, hierarchical-data

I have two basic models, a Command and a Flow.  Flows can contain a series of commands or other nested Flows.  So any given Flow can have a list of children that are either Step or Flow types.  (This is similar to Files and Directories you might model in a file system.)

I've tried to model this using ContentTypes, Generic relations, and mptt (which doesn't allow for generic content types AFAIK) but have had no success.  Here are my basic models:

```
class Step(models.Model):
    parent     = models.ForeignKey('Step', null=True)
    name        = models.CharField( max_length=100 )
    start_time  = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    end_time    = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    state       = models.CharField( max_length=1, default='u' )

class Flow(Step):
    type  = models.CharField( max_length=1 )

    def getChildren(self):
        # todo: the steps returned here need to be sorted by their order in the flow
        return Step.objects.filter(parent_id=self.parent_id)

    def run(self):
      for child in self.getChildren():
          print("DEBUG: run method processing a {0}".format(child.__class__.__name__) )
          # if this is a flow, run it
          # else if it's a command, execute it

class Command(Step):
    exec_string = models.TextField()
```

I want to be able to create Flows in my app, query the children, then process each child differently depending on its type (commands get executed, flows get recursively processed.)

I would appreciate any correction of my code above which would make this possible or even comments that I'm approaching this problem the complete wrong way for Django.

Edit: I should add that I'm using Python 3.3 and Django dev (to be named 1.6)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `abstract` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: I don't see how, but I'd welcome an example that would meet my requirements. I've used abstract classes, and Foreign Key fields can't point to them (which makes sense), so something else would be needed.

Comment: If a "Flow can have a list of children that are either Step or Flow types," how does the Flow know which order to process them?  Does it process all Steps first, or are they interleaved?  It seems like a Flow needs to sequence them somehow.

Comment: Brent, that is correct.  The Step class also has another attribute to order them.  I pared down the models to make the example easier and focus on the part that was difficult, the polymorphic relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an answer via some great help on IRC here and wanted to share it in case anyone else had the same problem.

The only thing I had to ultimately change was Flow.getChildren().

```
def getChildren(self):
    # Get a list of all the attrs relating to Child models.
    child_attrs = dict(
        (rel.var_name, rel.get_cache_name())
        for rel in Step._meta.get_all_related_objects()
        if issubclass(rel.field.model, Step) and isinstance(rel.field, models.OneToOneField)
    )

    objs = []
    for obj in self.children.all().select_related(*child_attrs.keys()):
        # Try to find any children...
        for child in child_attrs.values():
            sobj = obj.__dict__.get(child)
            if sobj is not None:
                break
        objs.append(sobj)
    return objs
```

If anyone has a cleaner solution I'd love to see it, especially since this seems like a lot of work for something it seems like the framework should handle more directly.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that jumps out at me is "return Step.objects.filter(parent_id=self.parent_id)". I believe it should be "return Step.objects.filter(parent__pk=self.parent.pk)"

Comment: The filtering actually wasn't the problem and was returning the correct objects.  The biggest problem is that they were being returned as Step objects rather than their subclasses.  I got a solution though and will be posting it in a moment.